# How to add watermark to every page pdf file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, watermark

I have pdf file. I want to add **watermark** in every page. I want to do it using javascript, or using library. How i do that?

i know one of managing pdf file, its called **jsPDF**. But i dont know how to use it to import existing pdf file, and add watermark.

So, the result is a new pdf file with watermark in every page.

Example add watermark online in this [link](https://www.sejda.com/watermark-pdf).

Edit :
That is not answer my question, because i need to **import existing pdf** file. How?

Comment: @str that is generated pdf file, i need to import existing pdf

Comment: You are looking for a completely client side solution? No server component? Are you open to commercial solutions?

Comment: @Ryan yes, completely client side if possible. if not, i will combine it with node.js. What do you mean for commercial solutions?

Comment: By commercial I meant a paid solution, or are you only looking for free (unpaid) solutions.

Comment: Im looking for free, its for my final project.